# Looping through table controls to get cell text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 6 tables named Seq(num)tab now I have a big operation of code to perform on each one rather do a massive switch case for each table I would rather have a loop which can loop through the tables basically like this (in theory) should do. obviously very stripped out for display purposes

```
for (int i = 1; i <= totalseq; i++)
{
    string originstart = (Table)Page.FindControl("Seq" + I + "Num").Rows[1].Cells[0].Text;

    // have also tried this

    string originstart = Page.FindControl("Seq" + I + "Num", as Table).Rows[1].Cells[0].Text;

    //lots of code using originstart
}
```

However I just get different errors why it wouldn't work ie. (1st example) does not contain definition for rows.  its a table control of course its got a rows definition lol

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your are doing invalid cast. Since you want to cast only the control you have found to the table, you need `((Table)Page.FindControl("Seq" + I + "Num")). ...` Note that it will only work if table is declared as a server-side control and is a direct child of the page

Comment: Spot On! add it as a answer and i'll flag it!

Comment: Done, please find the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Converted from the comment*

This code:

```
(Table)Page.FindControl("Seq" + I + "Num").Rows[1].Cells[0].Text
```

tries to execute all calls chain and then to cast the `Text` property to `Table`. What you really need is to cast the `FindControl` result to `Table`:

```
((Table)Page.FindControl("Seq" + I + "Num")).Rows[1].Cells[0].Text
```

Note additional parenthesis. Also note that this code will only work if table is declared as a server-side control and is a direct child of the page.

Comment: As Andrei has said has to be direct child of page, if inside a panel like mine was change Page.FindControl to *Panel ID*.FindControl. Just for reference.